# Python: randomly select from list of keys with maximum value in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I can get the first occurring key with maximum value by doing:

```
# history = {1: 1.0, 3: 5.0, 4: 5.0}
max_key = max(history, key=lambda key: history[key])
```

which will always return me 3. How would I change `max_key` so that it selects keys 3 or 4 randomly? I tried wrapping it by `np.random.choice()` but this gives me an error.

Comment: What does this have to do with numpy?

Comment: First you need a list of all keys with the maximum value.  It might be easier to work with the `history.items` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.random.choice([key for key in history.keys() if history[key]==max(history.values())])
```

Comment: I find this one the most clean/readable and intuitive especially without the lambda function or history.get(). Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean by quadratic time? Your answer seems to be very similar to this one, except this is in a single line using list comprehension, so I'm curious. (Also wondering why this answer was downvoted by someone)

Comment: @ru111 this one calls `max` inside the loop, causing it to have quadratic complexity. If you do not do this, you have linear complexity. Essentially, if you call `max(..)` inside the comprehension, *it iterates through `history.values()` every single iteration*. But that value never changes, and it's an expensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one step after your original approach:

```
import random
max_key = max(history, key=lambda key: history[key])
random.choice([i for i, j in history.items() if j == history[max_key]])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, find the maximum value:

```
>>> history = {1: 1.0, 3: 5.0, 4: 5.0}
>>> max_val = max(history.values())
```

Then get a list of keys with the maximum value:

```
>>> max_keys = [k for k in history if history[k] == max_val]
```

Then select from that list randomly:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(max_keys)
4
>>> random.choice(max_keys)
3
```

Comment: WHy not `max_val = max(history.values())`?

Comment: @Eric that would make a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.items()`:

```
import random  # you don't need numpy here
max_value = max(history.values())
random.choice([
    key
    for key, value in history.items()
    if value == max_value
])
```